# how to count specific character in text file using python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Exercise 7: Counting...1...2...3...
#The purpose of this program is to ask a file from the user, open the file 
# and counts the number of comma-separated values in it and report the result to the user

name_file = input("Enter name of file: ")

inf = open(name_file, "r")

count_comma = 0 


line = inf.readline()

for char in line:
    if "," in char:
       count_comma +=1

print (count_comma)
inf.close()
```

when i run it prints 0. why?

Comment: because `line` doesn't contain commas... you can achieve the same thing with `line.count(",")`

Comment: I'd update your question title to 'count the number of fields in a delimited string' -- and if my answer was satisfactory please accept it as such

Answer (score -1):

you're probably better off with

```
count_comma = len(line.split(","))
```

but you'd have to run timeit to be sure

Comment: Thank you @Schalton